# Facing issue while deploying laravel project on vercel (ready only file system)

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, server, vercel

[image: error]

I'm trying to deploy an open source project [bagisto](https://github.com/bagisto/bagisto) on vercel but I'm facing an issue which is shown in the image.

I have followed these steps to deploy a laravel project which are shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dERa0R2zLqc) and followed the bagisto installation steps.

I want to find a solution to this issue so I can deploy this project.

Comment: Instead of posting your git, please post a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

There is a need to give permission for that file.

Please follow the steps to resolve the issue.

1. Navigate to the folder inside your root directory of the project.

   **Project path -> storage -> framework -> cache.**
2. Here you can find the file named repository-cache-keys.json.
3. Here, you need to give permission for that file to be read and write.

After following these steps, if you have any issues, please let us know.

Thank you!

Comment: i tried changing the permission in windows but it;s working in local but not on vercel

Comment: The issue is only for file permission. Can you please try [this](https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/314#discussioncomment-3609594)?

Here you can find the solution to how to change file permission in Vercel.